# EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) when trying to create NSURLCredetial in Kotlin/Native

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

Does anyone know why I get `Thread 5: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)`, when trying to create NSURLCredetials in the iOS specific code of Kotlin multi-platform project. I get the error when this code is executed:

```
val credentials = NSURLCredential.credentialWithUser(this.username, this.password, NSURLCredentialPersistence.NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession)
```

And here is a bit more details about the error:

```
   0x10d8f83cb <+123>: leaq   0x87f02e(%rip), %rdi      ; __KonanTlsKey
    0x10d8f83d2 <+130>: movl   $0xe0, %esi
    0x10d8f83d7 <+135>: callq  0x10d1662e0               ; LookupTLS
->  0x10d8f83dc <+140>: leaq   0x87da7d(%rip), %rdi      ; kobjref:platform.Foundation.NSURLCredentialPersistence.$OBJECT#internal
    0x10d8f83e3 <+147>: leaq   0x6b8746(%rip), %rdx      ; ktype:platform.Foundation.NSURLCredentialPersistence.$OBJECT
    0x10d8f83ea <+154>: leaq   -0x691(%rip), %rcx        ; kfun:platform.Foundation.NSURLCredentialPersistence.$OBJECT.<init>()platform.Foundation.NSURLCredentialPersistence.$OBJECT at Foundation.kt
    0x10d8f83f1 <+161>: movq   %rax, %rsi
    0x10d8f83f4 <+164>: movq   -0x40(%rbp), %r8
```

Comment: Hello, I was unable to reproduce the error, can you please extend the question with a code snippet and instructions on it's running?

Comment: here you can find a small app that demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/afoo/ktcrashtest

Comment: Hello again, sorry for such a late response. Thank you for the project, I was able to reproduce the problem successfully. Please wait for an update here